# New Subscribe Button v Add Friend: Graph API or FQL Call...?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

Facebook added a twitter-like "Subscribe" button in the last several days that allows people to see your public updates w/o them being your friend.

1. If a user becomes a subscriber and NOT a friend...I assume they are NOT in the friends table. If so, what table are they in?
2. What is the proper Graph API call for subscribers?

Answer (score 1):

To get a list of a user's subscribers use this graph api call:

https://graph.facebook.com/adamfairbanks/subscribers

(Replace "adamfairbanks" with the user's user_id or username. For yourself you can also use "me".)

This call requires an access token. To make the call with an access token, you can use the Graph API Explorer:

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=adamfairbanks%2Fsubscribers

If you've never used the Graph API Explorer before, you may need to

1. click [Get Access Token]
2. click [Get Access Token] on the permissions dialog (no permissions need to be checked)
3. click [Login] to the Graph API Explorer
4. click [Submit] to resubmit the graph API call now with the access token

Change adamfairbanks to any facebook username or user_id that has enabled subscribers